# Action class getting null value from jsp page through ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

How can I get the JSP value from action class through Ajax? When I enter the username want to check to database the username is present or not. For that purpose, I am using Ajax.

Here my JSP code:

```xml
<script>    
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#username").change(function(){
      $("#message").html("checking...");    
      $("#message").css('color', 'red');
                            
                    var username=$("#username").val();
                    alert(username);
            
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"CheckUserAction",
                        data:"username="+username,
                        success:function(data){                        


//checking the code for username is present in database or not
                           }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<%@include file="index.html" %>
 <div class="box2">
    <center>
    <!-- <div class="header"></div> -->
    <center>
        <div class="outer"><center>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <div class="inner"><br /><br /><br />
        <center> 
            <s:form action="RegisterationProcess" id="loginForm"  name="loginForm" method="post" >
                <table width="auto" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="tab">

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><center><b>Registration Form</b></center></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
                </tr> 
                
                <input type="hidden" name="register" value="register"/>      
                <tr>     
                    <td><s:textfield name="user.userName"class="textfield" id="login" label="Name"/></td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>  
                    <td><s:textfield name="user.userId" id="username"  class="textfield" label="User Name" /> </td> 
                    <div id="message"></div>        
                </tr>`enter code here`
   
                <tr>  
                    <td><s:password name="user.password"  class="textfield" id="password" label="Password" /></td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr>
                    <td><s:textfield name="user.emailId" class="textfield" id="emailAddress" label="Email" /></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input id="sbmt" type="submit" value="Register"></td>
                <!-- <td><s:submit value="Register"  id="sbmt"/></td> -->
                </tr>
```

and this is my `CheckUserAction` class:

```
      private String userId;
    private String userName;
   
  public UserImpl getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

public void setUser(UserImpl user) 
{
    this.user = user;
}


public String getUserName() 
{
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) 
{
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserId()
{
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) 
{
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String execute()
{
  System.out.println("username"+userName);
}
}
```

I am getting username as `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `data:"username="+username,`
to `data: {userName:username}`

See [example from the documentation of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

Comment: thanks..but i want to know in java class why iam getting the null value for username

Comment: after changing userName, are you still facing null?

Comment: @user2653831: It shouldn't...Can you try with hardcoded value from ajax, i.e data: { userName: "test"} , please check your bean property name should match with userName in data

Answer (score 0):

Typo: `data:"username="+username` should be `data:"userName="+username`

And to avoid this kind of errors, you can name your javascript variable `userName` too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
           $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"CheckUserAction",
                    data:{"username": username },
                    success:function(data){  

                    //checking the code for username is present in database or not
                    }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url:"<s:url action='CheckUserAction'/>",
  data: { userName: username }
  success:function(data){                            
     //checking the code for username is present in database or not
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `data: {"username":username},` instead of `data:"username="+username,`